# Direction of magnetic flux in magnetic circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, coil, magnetic-flux

[image]

[image]

In the first picture attached,we see a ring shaped magnetic circuit with two magnetomotive forces. Now,in the solution to this problem,it was said that the two sources generate flux in the same direction and hence the net MMF is \$N_1I_1+N_2I_2\$.

However in the 2nd picture attached,we see an iron core magnetic circuit with $2$ magnetomotive sources as well. But in this case,as the book says,the two sources generate flux in the opposite direction(*without any explanation why,they just made an analogy with electrical circuits*) and hence the net flux results in \$N_1I_1-N_2I_2\$.
Both the circuits are from Introductory Circuit Analysis by Boylestead. But I don't see any difference in the orientation of the two sources in both the pictures. So,why was addition done one and subtraction done in the other? Is there any way to differentiate the two pictures or how is the direction of flux assigned as per the current flow?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example we can show the equivalent circuit like this: -

[image]

I've added the word "flipped" in red to show the difference. And, the reason why is because of the directions of current that I've emphasized in red below: -

[image]

I expect that in the 2nd example, the current directions are different (although this is impossible to tell from diagram 12.16).